# src attribute of <img> is missing when sending mail

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send a HTML mail from php that contains an image.

I receive the email and all the HTML tags look good except for the `<img>` tag.

The message of the email looks like this:

`$message = '<img src="http://your-click.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/logo1.png" alt="Your Click" width="131" height="52" border="0" />';`

When I receive the mail, I see that there is an image but it is just blank. When I check the element, I see this code:

```
<img alt="Your Click" width="131" height="52" border="0">
```

As you see the whole src attribute is missing? Why?

Comment: The `/>` also got replaced with `>`, so the HTML got parsed on the way. Maybe your mail software strips images?

Comment: Most mail clients strip out images due to their abuse for tracking whether emaul addresses are valid for spammers

Comment: Is there a message at the top asking you to download the image?

Comment: @HelloUniverse yes, it is. Is there a way to force downloading the image?

Comment: Not that I know of; unfortunately I feel it is built in to the email client that you probably can not  get around with. What you can do is provide alt text that will show when the image is not displayed. That way, atleast there is something on the screen. When image download is allowed, then user sees everything

Answer (score 4):

Some email clients filter out externally linked images for security reasons.  Try encoding the image and including it in the body of your message instead of externally linking it.

Comment: It is not always possible to encode all images in an email. me including many others have successfully used external images

Answer (score 4):

The image is probably being filtered by the recipient mail server, try  [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) the image, i.e.:

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://your-click.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/logo1.png');
$message = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'" alt="Your Click" width="131" height="52" border="0" />';
```

Comment: I've had a similar issue before and base64 is how I solved it, so this gets my vote

Comment: I tried that code but I still have the same problem. The src attribute won't appear.

Comment: Have you tried sending to a different recipient ? if so, what was the result?

Comment: I've had a similar issue before and the above answer solved it, so this gets my vote.

Answer (score 1):

See if the following helps

```
$message = '<img src="http://your-click.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/logo1.png" alt="Your Click" width="131" height="52" border="0" style="width:131px; height:52px; border:0px; background:url('http://your-click.ch/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/logo1.png')" />';
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. What I get is: `<img style="width:131px;min-height:52px;border:0px;background:url('')" alt="Your Click" width="131" height="52" border="0">`